# What is the RegEx equivalent of ".-" in Lua's pattern matching?

Tags: javascript, regex, lua, lua-patterns

I'm porting some Lua code to JS and I haven't worked with Lua so far.
There's the Lua pattern `"^([^aeiouàèéêíòóôúïü]*)(.-)$"` and I found the following explanation for the hyphen [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial):

> - Match the previous character (or class) zero or more times, as few times as possible.

I'm trying to figure out what the equivalent as a regular expression would be. Also I don't understand why this is needed in the first place - wouldn't ending in `(.*)$` suffice?

Comment: "wouldn't ending in (.*)$ suffice?" It'd be equivalent, but I guess `.-` expresses some intent as "Match as few characters as possible"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, `.-` is actually equivalent of `[\s\S]*?` or `(?s).*?`, or - to play it safe - `(?s:.*?)`, because `.` in Lua patterns matches any char (including line break chars) and `-` is the lazy (non-greedy) quantifier that matches 0 or more chars, i.e. `*?` in regular NFA regex.

See [Lua patterns](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html):

> `. all characters`

And then

> The `` `+´ `` modifier matches one or more characters of the original class. It will always get the longest sequence that matches the pattern.
> The modifier `` `*´ `` is similar to `` `+´ ``, but it also accepts zero occurrences of characters of the class...
>   Like `` `*´ ``, the modifier `` `-´ `` also matches zero or more occurrences of characters of the original class. However, instead of matching the longest sequence, it matches the shortest one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that pattern is pretty much equivalend to the corresponding regex in many languages. Javascript seems to not have the `-` quantifier, but you should be able to replace it with `.*` and it should still work.

Try `"^([^aeiouàèéêíòóôúïü]*)(.*)$"`

Of course, you can also test this in the Lua REPL:

```
Lua 5.3.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2018 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> orig = '^([^aeiou]*)(.-)$'
> modif = '^([^aeiou]*)(.*)$'
> ("jhljkhaaaasjkdf"):match(orig)
jhljkh  aaaasjkdf
> ("jhljkhaaaasjkdf"):match(modif)
jhljkh  aaaasjkdf
> -- QED
```